# Standard/Uniform way to locate files inside and outside JAR file?

Tags: java, jar, file-access

What is the uniform or standard way to locate and then access files inside and outside JAR files.

I have InJarClass() defined in JAR file which contains configuration text files.
Then I extend this class in my host project which have more configurations.

Let say I have inside the JAR :

```
config/default.conf
```

Then in the host project I do :

```
class MyClass extends InJarClass { .... }
```

and also :

```
config/test.conf
```

then I run it something like this :

XENV=test java myclass

The whole configuration process happens inside InJarClass(), based on environment XENV.
As you see InJarClass() have to access both :

```
<jar>/config/default.conf
<host_app_dir>/config/test.conf
```

So to repeat my question is there uniform way to access both, if the directory structure mirror each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place both the current directory and the .jar file in your classpath:

```
XENV=test java -classpath .:myjarfile.jar MyClass
```

you can do this:

```
String configFile =
    "/config/" +
    System.getenv().getOrDefault("XENV", "default") +
    ".conf";

InputStream config = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(configFile);

if (config == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException(
        "Cannot locate " + configFile + " in classpath");
}
```

This works because an application resource is a resource which Java searches for within each location in the classpath.  So getResourceAsStream will first search for the requested path relative to the first classpath location, `.`.  If it does not find a file with that name, it will look at the second classpath location, `myjarfile.jar`, and seeing that it is a .jar file, will search for the requested file *inside* that .jar.

Comment: I see. Can I use getResource() to get just the absolute path instead of a Stream.

Comment: hmmm... I have to use Stream, I can not read it like a file from inside the .jar, right ?

Comment: You can use [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) instead of getResourceAsStream, to get a URL instead of an InputStream.  You cannot get a file name, because when the file is found inside a .jar, it isn't a separate file.